# Story ID: Group of boys vanish descending lighthouse stairs

Tags: story-identification

I think this was a short story, part of a collection of ghost stories or the like, read in English around the early 90s.  Not sure about publication date.

A group of boys (maybe from a school or a scout troop) are spending the night at the top of an old lighthouse (could be some other tall building, but pretty sure it's a lighthouse).  Various eerie events happen, and at some point they are sent down the many stairs to leave the building.  The conclusion is that they disappear, never reaching the bottom, with perhaps a final note about how the sound of their footsteps on the stairs can still be heard.

Comment: Are any supernatural entities actually observed at the lighthouse? Because then the story would share even more similarities with SCP-087.